# How to loop through JSON parameters in android

Tags: java, android, json

suppose I have a JSON that prints out

```
{"_id"              :"4e3f2c6659f25a0f8400000b",
 "confirmation_code":"TWLNX8BT",
 "confirmed"        :true,
 "created_at"       :"2011-08-08T00:23:02+00:00",
 "email_address"    :"dd5dc43ea6bf12ec604b0a7025b94105d419616b",
 "first_name"       :"sean",
 "invites"          :[],
 "last_name"        :"pan",
 "raw_email_address":null,
 **"tracking_users" :[{ 
                        "_id"       :"4e407f0659f25a1ce9000007",
                        "active"    :true,
                        "first_name":"Sean",
                        "last_name" :"Pan",
                        "user_id"   :"4e3da65e59f25a3956000005"
                     },{
                        "_id"       :"4e407f7a59f25a1d19000007",
                        "active"    :true,
                        "first_name":"Sean",
                        "last_name" :"Pan",
                        "user_id"   :"4e3da65e59f25a3956000005"
                     },{
                        "_id"       :"4e4085c959f25a204b000004", 
                        "active"    :true,
                        "first_name":"Sean",
                        "last_name" :"Pan",
                        "user_id"   :"4e3da65e59f25a3956000005"
                     }],
 "updated_at"       :"2011-08-08T06:44:31+00:00",
 "user_id"          :137141}**
```

in the tracking users part I have three "different" (they're the same for testing purposes) JSON strings within the original JSON. How do I go through the inner parameter (user_id[0]),(user_id[1]),(user_id[2])... of tracking_users in a for loop for android?

I am turning my JSON into a string and then using 
obj = new org.json.JSONObject(response) to change it into an object then I use
String trackingusers=obj.getString("tracking_users") to get the three objects in the tracking_users variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get tracking_users as JSONArray, then loop them as JSONObject, and with the JSONObject, you can get it's properties, try this:

```
JSONArray tracking_users = obj.getJSONArray("tracking_users");
for (int i = 0; i < tracking_users.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject user = tracking_users.getJSONObject(i);
    String _id = user.getString("_id");
    and etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getJSONArray("tracking_users")` and process each item in the array as an JSONObject.

Comment: Thanks that helped but can you tell me how to process each item as a JSONObject? For now I have JSONArray jsonarray=obj.getJSONArray("tracking_users"); jsonarray[0] does nothing etc

Comment: It depends on what you actually need to do, but basically extract the data you need using getString(), etc. See the first answer for some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is composed from Objects and Array of objects. The whole result string is an object. So you loaded it fine. After that, you have to process tracking_users as Array of Objects. So use:

```
JSONAeeay users = obj.getJSONArray("tracking_users");
```

and with this, you can cycle through the objects:

```
int users_count = users.length();
for (int i=0; i<users_count; i++)
{
    users.getJSONObject(i)
}
```